# Attaching images to multiple galleries

Tags: media, media-library

I've been wondering about this image/gallery issue for ages.

So, I've got some images:

lifestyle1.jpg, lifestyle2.jpg, lifestyle3.jpg, lifestyle4.jpg, kids1.jpg, kids2.jpg, kids3.jpg, outdoors1.jpg, outdoors2.jpg, etc....

I want to have three galleries:

1. **Homepage** —a mixture of all photos
2. **Lifestyle** —just lifestyle
3. **Outdoors** — just outdoors
4. **Kids**— just kids

I can obviously make a page called Lifestyle, attach the lifestyles images and I'm all set with my Lifestyle gallery.

How do I make my Homepage gallery a mixture of all pictures? ie:

**Homepage**
- lifestyle1.jpg, lifestyle2.jpg, kids2.jpg, outdoors1.jpg

When all these photos are already in the media library. It seems so basic, yet I can't see a way to do it besides re-attaching and re-uploading the same images again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you open `wp-includes/media.php` file you will see such code in `gallery_shortcode` function:

```
...
if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    ...
}
...
```

It means that you can use gallery shortcode with `include` attribute, where you can insert ids of all images which you require for gallery:

```
[gallery include="45,59,61,62"]
```